# XML - validate to the specific character

Tags: regex, xml, validation

Is it possible in CDATA section in XML to validate to the specific character?

I have some sequence, for example:

```
12355425asdasc|asdadaasd|131231231
```

and I want to have only sequence before first appearance of  "|" character which is:

```
12355425asdasc
```

Maybe is it possible with regex expression?

I know that I can validate first few characters if the first part of sequence will be constant, but what if first sequence is changeable? In this example first sequence has 15 characters, but what if first sequence will have 20 characters or 10 characters?

Comment: [`(\w+)\|`](https://regex101.com/r/fqQoyF/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^\w+(?=\|)
```

That's if you can have positive lookaheads in XML

[See it here](https://regex101.com/r/XEHZeG/1)

Answer (score 2):

```
(.+?)\|
```

if you can't have positive lookaheads